# Creating one plot with two different y- axes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create one plot with two different scaled y-axes in ggplot2. I tried several different suggestions that I already found online, but it still does not work for my data .I've got count data as well as temperature data related to one specific month in a year:

```
 $ Month     : chr  "11-2016" "12-2016" "01-2017" "10-2017" ...
 $ Amount    : int  67 118 2 62 60 60 53 89 189 223 ...
 $ GroundTemp: num  3.8 0.5 -2.9 11.5 4.5 3.6 0.3 4.7 5.1 1.8 ...
 $ AirTemp   : num  3.9 0.68 -3.62 10.38 4.25 ...
```

I would like to create a plot, representing the month on the x-axis and the "Amount" as well as "AirTemp" on two different y-axes. Whereby the data refering to "Amount" should be represented as barplot and the "AirTemp" as a line.

That's the data set that I'm working with:

`structure(list(Month = c("11-2016", "12-2016", "01-2017", "10-2017",  "11-2017", "01-2018", "02-2018", "11-2018", "11-2019", "12-2019",  "01-2020", "11-2020", "12-2020"), Amount = c(67L, 118L, 2L, 62L,  60L, 60L, 53L, 89L, 189L, 223L, 31L, 138L, 10L), GroundTemp = c(3.8,  0.5, -2.9, 11.5, 4.5, 3.6, 0.3, 4.7, 5.1, 1.8, 1.4, 10.3, 1.6 ), AirTemp = c(3.9, 0.68, -3.62, 10.38, 4.25, 4.3, -2.09, 4.89,  4.64, 3.01, 2.51, 9.38, 2.41)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -13L))`

I tried many different ways of getting there and I think that's the closes one:

```
  geom_line(aes(y=AirTemp,color="2"),linetype=1, size=2)+
  geom_point(aes(y=AirTemp, color="2"),size=4)+
  geom_line(aes(y=Amount,color="1"),linetype=1, size=2)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Amount, color="1"),size=4)
```

[That's the resulting plot, colour 1 represents the "Amount" and colour 2 the "AirTemp"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ0Eq.png)

I don't get any further than this. Could you may help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: To help us to help you would you mind to add a snippet of your data via `dput()`? To post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post. If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first twenty rows. See also [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Isn't `sec_axis()` in `scale_y_...` statement working? This seems to be great to answer your problem, but as you said "I tried several different suggestions", I'm curious to know why this isn't working for you.

Comment: some examples with `sec_axis`: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html

Comment: @stefan: I've added my data to the post

Comment: @MonJeanJean: I'm curious as well. It seems to be problematic that I do not have data for each month, and that I only have one data point for each month...

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks I'm gonna check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. I ordered the `Month` as they appear in the data
2. For the line you have to add the `group` aes as your x-axis variable is a character or factor. Otherwise you don't get a line.
3. For the `Amount` I switched to `geom_col`
4. I set the colors via `scale_xxx_manual`
5. For the secondary axis you (probably) have to transform your data and reverse this transformation via the `trans` argument of `sec_axis`. Here I simply scaled by 20 to make the scale of `AirTemp` roughly the same as the one of `Amount`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

# Set order of Month as they appear in data
d$Month <- forcats::fct_inorder(d$Month)

ggplot(d, aes(x = Month)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = Amount, fill = "amount")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = AirTemp * 20, color = "airtemp", group = 1), linetype = 1, size = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = AirTemp * 20, color = "airtemp"), size = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(amount = "blue")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(airtemp = "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ .x / 20, name = "AirTemp"))
```

[image]